# Using strings form list inside a loop as variables

Tags: python

This is newbie question. I am working on something called sagemath which is completely based on Python.

My code is two parts:
The first part is:

```
var('a,b')
my_list=list(powerset([a,b]))
my_possible_products_list=[]
for i in my_list:
        if len(i)!=0:
            my_possible_products_list.append(prod(i))
print my_possible_products_list
```

with an ouput

```
[a, b, a*b]
```

i.e, the result is a list of all possible product expressions on a set of two variables.

The second part:

```
for expression_compute in my_possible_products_list:
    for l in range(1,3):
        for a in divisors(l):
            for b in divisors(l):
                print expression_compute
```

with an output

```
a
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
b
a*b
a*b
a*b
a*b
a*b
```

The problem: I need to have numerical output, not using a and b, but using the values of a and b as divisors of the given l.

Any hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question here, but to my understanding you have the expression as a string and want to compute the value. For a and b as single entities it's easy, just cast to integer

```
a = "5"
print(int(a) + 1)  # Will print 6
```

for the product expression you could do as @iForest suggests using **eval()** but as he said that is evil. I would use the **split** method

```
expr = "3*5"
terms = expr.split('*') 
print(int(terms[0]) * int(terms[1]))  # Will print 15
```

hope this helps, otherwise I need more explanation of your problem

== Updates after @iForest comment  ==

If it is the variables names as strings that are needed use `locals()`

```
a = 3
b = 5
variables = locals()
expr = "a*b"
terms = expr.split('*')
print(variables[terms[0]] * variables[terms[1]])  # Output 15
```

will work as long as you don't need to update the variables

Comment: I think `expr` is something like `a*b`.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps `locals()` is the way to go since no updates to `a`or `b` are made. There is no good way to give example of this in comment field so will update my answer instead

Answer (score 0):

Built-in function [eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) can evaluate value of string.

```
a = 3
b = 5
print(eval("a * b"))        # Output 15
```

But yes, **eval() is EVIL**.

It's easy and quick to use, but be careful when you use it. You have to make sure the input string you eval() is OK. Read more about how to use / how dangerous [here](http://www.diveintopython3.net/advanced-iterators.html) (8.9. Evaluating Arbitrary Strings As Python Expressions).

Comment: Don't use `eval` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice